# How far can someone be manipulated?

Tags: apocalypse-world

I'm trying to figure exactly how manipulation works.

> When you  try to seduce or manipulate someone, tell them what you want and roll+hot. For NPCs: on a hit, they ask you to promise something first, and do it if you promise. On a 10+, whether you keep your promise is up to you, later. On a 7–9, they need some concrete assurance right now. For PCs: on a 10+, both. On a 7–9, choose 1:
>   •  if they do it, they mark experience [the carrot]
>   •  if they refuse, it’s acting under fire [the stick]
>   What they do then is up to them.

I understand  that to manipulate, you need leverage. Does a player having leverage on an Npc mean that player can make the NPC do pretty much anything? Or does the MC get to decide how much that leverage is "worth" and limit what the player can get the NPC to do?

For example:
NPC is a super drug head. Player has access to top quality drugs. That's pretty good leverage on the NPC. The player tries to manipulate  the NPC into shooting himself in the head. Can the MC say "No, even if you have all the drugs in the world, there is no way you can get this guy to shoot himself"? Or does the MC have to let the player roll and go with the results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GM's Agenda: "Make Apocalypse World seem real".

Would someone shoot themselves in the head for drugs?  No.

Apocalypse World tries to make it very easy to avoid ridiculous outcomes by giving a good set of guidelines: the Moves exist under the direction of the Principles, the Principles aim towards the Agenda.  So yes, there are limits to Manipulation, and it's about what makes sense in light of the other rules given to you.

Answer (score 6):

The leverage has to make sense for what they're asking. The drug seller wants high quality drugs, but not in an abstract sense. They want to sell drugs and turn profit. They'll have no use for quality product if they're dead, imprisoned, or otherwise unable to actually do anything with it.

Which isn't to say you can't use this move to convince someone to kill themselves (well this is dark). If you threaten their loved ones, for instance, the leverage is still relevant even if the drug dealer dies - their loved ones get to live. In this case, dice may decide whether the drug dealer cares about them that much.

Answer (score 5):

You can make them do *quite a lot*. But no, your example doesn't work, because “I'll give you drugs if you kill yourself” is not really leverage for that action, is it? Like [Archimedes said](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Archimedes), you can move the world with a lever, but only if you have the right place to put it. So you can go ahead and try that, but the move just won't trigger until, in the course of the Conversation between you and the MC, what leverage you reveal and what you want combine to trigger the move (if at all).

(For example, you could instead offer those drugs to let you stay the night. Then when Druggie is passed out cold, wrap his fingers around his own pistol's grip and force his finger to pull the trigger. Mission accomplished! Just slightly differently, and don't get caught…)

But **seduce or manipulate** can do a very lot, otherwise. Given that drug-head and a pile of awesome drugs, you could get them to betray their beloved, murder their alpha wolf, betray their kin, or put themselves into danger for you — *if you roll well*.

If you don't, that's where the limits come in. That's the thing with Apocalypse World: it does not say “no, that's too hard”. If there's a chance to pull something off, it's possible and it will happen on a 7+, guaranteed.† Where the game brings in difficulty is by adjusting the *risk* involved, but you'll never see it up-close except on that 6−. Try to offer awesome drugs to manipulate that druggie to betray Big Boss Kreider, who's always been good to the loyal druggie and is vicious to his enemies, and roll a 6−? Guess who's actually going to get betrayed, and strung up for the vultures? Oh yeah, you guessed right. And getting out of *that* mess will be nasty, entertaining work.

<sup>† Some restrictions apply on 7–9, offer void in Quebec and Maine.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The *World games work on a logic of "fiction first".

If you are asking something that makes no sense for the character to do in the fiction, then they will not do it.

So your example, "I'll give you the drugs you're addicted to if you shoot yourself in the head" would only work if the character was so far gone that he thought he could actually use those drugs after shooting himself.

Answer (score 3):

There's a line in the AW rules that goes, loosely, "to do it, you do it." It's not that you set out to Manipulate or Seduce and then roll; when in the course of play, the circumstance comes up when you find yourself making a manipulative suggestion or a seductive offer and you need to figure out how it ends up, you make the move. If you offer someone drugs in exchange for their suicide, that's not going to trigger the move unless they are already prone to killing themselves.

Answer (score 3):

MC saying an outright *"No!"* is somewhat a *faux-pas* in *world games. However there's a good MC principle that helps when a player wants to do something ridiculous even by apocalyptic standards.

## Ask questions like crazy

> — You want him to shoot himself in the head in order to give him the drugs? How do you convince him that those drugs will be good for him when there's a hole in his brain?
>
> — Aw… well I say… uh… nevermind.‡

<sup>‡ I couldn't think of a plausible answer</sup>